# Did the כלי המקדש (menorah, shulchan, etc) need to be made לשמה?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle, menorah--in-temple

When they were made did they need to be made leshem menoras hamikdash, leshem shulchan shel hamikdash, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Yes all keilim need to be made lishma.

Rambam (courtsey of Chabad) Bais Habechira 1:20:

אֵין עוֹשִׂין כָּל הַכֵּלִים מִתְּחִלָּתָן אֶלָּא לְשֵׁם הַקֹּדֶשׁ. וְאִם נַעֲשׂוּ מִתְּחִלָּתָן לְהֶדְיוֹט אֵין עוֹשִׂין אוֹתָן לְגָבוֹהַּ. וּכְלִי גָּבוֹהַּ עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן גָּבוֹהַּ רַשַּׁאי לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן הֶדְיוֹט. וּמִשֶּׁנִּשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן גָּבוֹהַּ אֲסוּרִין לְהֶדְיוֹט. אֲבָנִים וְקוֹרוֹת שֶׁחֲצָבָן מִתְּחִלָּה לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת אֵין בּוֹנִין אוֹתָן לְהַר הַבַּיִת:

English translation (courtesy of Chabad):
All the [Temple's] utensils must initially be made for sacred purposes.93If they were initially made for mundane uses,94 they may not be used for [the Temple's] sake.95

A vessel [intended to be used for the Temple], but which was never used for [the Temple] may be used for mundane purposes. Once it has been used for [the Temple], it may not be used for mundane purposes.96

Stones or boards which were originally hewn for use in a synagogue should not be used in the Temple Mount construction.97